# How to get json value from json array column in postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a column which its type is character varying.

It contains a json array in it.

Something like below.

```
[
{"name":"Peter", "information":{"tel":"120391083", "address":"xxx"}},
{"name":"Jane", "information":{"tel":"12302131093", "address":"ooo"}},
{"name":"Pat", "information":{"tel":"123098", "address":"zzz"}}
]
```

How can I get the address value of json object which name is Pat?

I used -> and ->> operator but it showed operator does not exist.

I'm using pdadmin 4 and postgreSQL version is 13.2

Comment: JSON values should be stored in a `jsonb` column, not in a `varchar` column. This would be so much easier if you had a properly normalized data model.

Comment: This column is designed by others. I was trying to cast this column to jsonb and using the -> / ->> operator, but it didn't work.

Comment: Then tell those "others" that using `varchar` to store JSON values is not really a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what the output is exactly you are looking for.

If you want to get the full `information` part, you can use this:

```
select jsonb_path_query_first(the_column::jsonb, '$[*] ? (@.name == "Pat").information')
from the_table;
```

If you only what the value of the `address` key, you can use:

```
select jsonb_path_query_first(the_column::jsonb, '$[*] ? (@.name == "Pat").information') ->> 'address'
from the_table;
```

In any case you should change the column's data type to `jsonb` in the long run. Don't (mis)use `varchar` for that.